# Which keyboard buttons do I use to get the OR sign "||" in mac?

Tags: macos

Which keyboard buttons do I use to get the OR sign "||"  in mac?

I'm new to mac:S

Comment: How did you type this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold <Shift> and press <\>.

Comment: @Woho87: What country is the keyboard from?

Comment: Sweden, but I got it it is holding <alt> and press <7> in my keyboard

Comment: @Woho: In that case, Hold <AltGr> and press <<>

Comment: @Woho87: using a Swedish keyboard layout, looks like you want to use `Alt+TheKeyJustToTheRightOfTheLeftShiftKey`  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Swedish

Answer (score 1):

It's not one key.  It's two: "|" and "|"